# Multivariate Regression Analysis in SPSS

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis

I am using SPSS to perform a multivariate regression analysis. I have 4 factors, Group (1,2), AgeGroup (1,2), Sex (0,1), and handedness (0.1) with 4 dependent variables.
My question relates to interpretation of the outputs.
The ANOVA table presents interactions and main effects which is pretty straight forward.

It is the Beta coefficients that I am wondering about. Beta coefficients are not provided for each of the parameters. Does this relate to a default used by SPSS when the model is created??

Thanks

Comment: Although asked in terms of SPSS, the OP states that the question is about interpretation of the output. That is a statistical issue. IMO, this question should be considered on topic here.

Comment: Can you paste in the output that you got? Can you state the code or options you selected to get the output?

Answer (score 1):

I think for your factors variables one level (such as male or female)'s $\beta$ will be set to zero automactically, this level is called the referece group. It also called overparameterise for your design matrix since there are linear dependent between the columns of your indicator variables for your factors.
Such as you have a design matrix, the first column is intercept, second column is male, third is female, you can see the sceond(male) and third colmn(female) are linear dependent you need to omit one colunm to solve the linear equations.

$\begin{bmatrix}
 1&1  &0 \\ 
 1&1  &0 \\ 
 1&0  &1 \\ 
 1&0  &1 \\ 
 1&0  &1 \\ 
 1&1  &0 
\end{bmatrix}$